# Shopify If in collection then display this

Tags: shopify

I am trying to write a simple if statement, but always struggle with shopify's system.

Essentially I want it to do this:

**{% if collection.product == 'discontinued' %}
This Product is Discontinued.
{% endif %}**

If it's in this collection, then display this text/html.  Otherwise it wouldn't display anything.  This would be in the product.liquid template.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what ended up working:

```
{% for c in product.collections %}
{% if c.handle == "discontinued" %}
This product is Discontinued 
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create an array of the collections for a product using map on `product.collections`. This which will create a new array with your specified property, i.e. the handles of each collection.

You can then check if this new array `contains` the handle you want to work with.

```
{% assign productCollections = product.collections | map: "handle" %}
{% if productCollections contains 'your-collection-handle' %} 
  {% comment %} DoSomething {% endcomment %} 
{% endif %}
```

So for your example:

```
{% assign productCollections = product.collections | map: "handle" %}
{% if productCollections contains 'discontinued' %} 
  This product is Discontinued
{% endif %}
```

You can map other fields if your case is different, such as the title.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will help any one, I have used in the sidebar of shopify website.
The current collection page will get checked by this below code.

```
<div class="row-fluid not-animated" data-animate="fadeInUp">
<div class="title">By Collections</div>
<form class="coll">
{% assign col_tags = collection.title %}

{% for collection in collections %}

<input type="radio" value="{{ collection.url }}" name="collections"  {% if col_tags contains collection.title %} checked {% endif %} >{{ collection.title | escape }} <br/>

 {% endfor %}
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand how liquid collections work in Shopify, you will need to iterate over all of your products.

You'd need to do something similar to this if you are working with collections directly:

```
{% for product in collection.product %}
  {% if product.tags contains 'discontinued' %}
    This product has been discontinued :(
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you are just working with a single product you can probably just use the inner `if` liquid tag part.

References:

- [Collection.liquid](http://wiki.shopify.com/Collection.liquid)
- [Product.liquid](http://wiki.shopify.com/Product.liquid)

Comment: So you don't think there's a way to target a collection on a product page outside of using tags?  I mean I could use tags for the discontinued products, but would prefer to target them by adding them to a discontinued "collection".  Hopefully that makes sense..

Comment: Oh sure you could do that too.  But you'll need to inspect the title of the collection, not the products :)

Comment: I have done this particular
`code:
{% for product in collections['discontinued'].products %}
   This product has been discontinued :(
{% endfor %}
`
But it attempts to display a listing of the discontinued products rather than just display my message.  I am still trying to work through this though.

Comment: Oh and it does that for all products, regardless of which collection it is in.

Really disliking how Shopify does their setup.

Comment: Once you get over the initial learning curve of Liquid and using templates, you might like it. The alternatives are for the most part much worse.

Comment: Looping through collections the product belongs to is much cleaner than looping through all products in a collection. Loop through 3 collections vs. Loop through 5,000 products.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed add discontinued products to a collection called discontinued.

When rendering a product, you could do as csaunders suggests, simply loop through all the products in the discontinued collection, and check if the id of the current product matches any of the products in that collection. If so, do what you must do. No need to use tags.

Comment: If you have a large number of products this would cause a performance impact. It would be much easier/faster to loop through the collections that a product belongs to than to loop through all the products in a collection

Comment: I disagree that's the case. Can you demonstrate what you suggest is faster?

Comment: I'm not a math wizard, but... Say you are looping through 5,000 products in a collection and you're comparing to see if the product ID matches one of those vs. product belongs in 3 collections and you're comparing to see if one of those 3 is 'discountinued'. How would looping through 5,000 ever be faster than looping through 3?